# Closures in go routines have incorrect scope unless the variables are copied

Tags: go

I am seeing incorrect values in the functions run as goroutines. They don't seem to be capturing the values from the scope in which they were invoked unless copied into new variables.

http://play.golang.org/p/YZYi-IVuYm

vs.

http://play.golang.org/p/z88G99XSi6

Comment: (1) What question are you asking? (2) You'll get faster responses if you included the code in the body of the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You either need to re-assign the variable in the local context so that the closure can capture the values:

http://play.golang.org/p/-NO4S4qCZf

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    l := []int{1, 2, 3}
    for idx, item := range l {
        theIdx, theItem := idx, item
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(theIdx, theItem)
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

or you pass the values to the goroutine and add parameters to the function

http://play.golang.org/p/5gNToDWSQR

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    l := []int{1, 2, 3}
    for idx, item := range l {
        go func(idx, item int) {
            fmt.Println(idx, item)
        }(idx, item)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Comment: Note that passing *pointers* as parameters to the go routine will NOT work. So reassigning local variables is better in that case (see my example below).

Answer (score 9):

This is expected, and documented in the Go "[Common Mistakes](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CommonMistakes)" page.  You can argue with the design decision, but it is a known effect.

A recommended way to do this is to pass the values in as parameters.

Comment: Note that passing *pointers* as parameters to the go routine will NOT work. So reassigning local variables is better in that case (see my example below).

Answer (score 2):

By the time the first goroutine is executed, `idx` and `item` have already been overwritten with the next values. As the routines are executed within the same scope, you get the new values.

It does make sense, in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

Note that passing **pointers** in as parameters to a go routine is still problematic:

Does NOT work:

https://play.golang.org/p/kAnJsIJCyNF

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    l := []int{1, 2, 3}
    for idx, item := range l {
        go func(idx int, itemAddr *int) {
            fmt.Println(idx, *itemAddr)
        }(idx, &item)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

So reassigning variables locally is the way to go in this case:

WORKS:

https://play.golang.org/p/wgNFDi5TN-9

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    l := []int{1, 2, 3}
    for idx, item := range l {
        theIdx, theItem := idx, item
        go func() {
            theItemAddr := &theItem
            fmt.Println(theIdx, *theItemAddr)
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```