# How does Golang share variables between goroutines?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm learning Go and trying to understand its concurrency features.

I have the following program.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        x := i

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println(x)
        }()

    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

When executed I got:

```
4
0
1
3
2
```

It's just what I want. However, if I make slight modification to it:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println(i)
        }()

    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

What I got will be:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

I don't quite understand the difference. Can anyone help to explain what happened here and how Go runtime execute this code?

Comment: See the faq: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: Also see [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196200/closures-in-go-routines-have-incorrect-scope-unless-the-variables-are-copied,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919213/why-does-golang-handle-closures-differently-in-goroutines

Comment: See also the interactive [Go Traps](http://go-traps.appspot.com/#rendezvous-iteration)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have new variable on each run of `x := i`,
This code shows difference well, by printing the address of `x` inside goroutine:
[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1JYo6CWK5n):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        x := i
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println(&x)
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

output:

```
0xc0420301e0
0xc042030200
0xc0420301e8
0xc0420301f0
0xc0420301f8
Done
```

---

And build your second example with `go build -race` and run it:
You will see: `WARNING: DATA RACE`

---

And this will be fine [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k9jQzDcDYt):

```golang
//go build -race
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println(i)
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

output:

```
0
4
1
2
3
Done
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot to understand the logical behind.

Comment: Is the last example fine because there the variable `i` gets copied when the coroutine function is started/called?

Comment: @xuiqzy pass a value to a new goroutine, not reference it in the goroutine.

Answer (score 7):

The general rule is, don't share data between goroutines. In the first example, you essentially give each goroutine their own copy of `x`, and they print it out in whatever order they get to the print statement. In the second example, they all reference the same loop variable, and it is incremented to 5 by the time any of them print it. I don't believe the output there is guaranteed, it just happens that the loop creating goroutines finished faster than the goroutines themselves got to the printing part.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to explain in plain english, but I'll try my best.

You see, every time you spawn a new goroutine, there is an initialization time, no matter how minuscule it might be, it's always there. So, in your second case, the entire loop has finished incrementing the variable 5 times before any of the goroutines even started. And when the goroutines finish initialization, all they see is the final variable value which is 5.

In your first case though, the x variable keeps a copy of the i variable so that when the goroutines start, x get's passed to them. Remember, it is `i` that is being incremented here, not `x`. `x` is fixed. So, when the goroutines start, they get a fixed value.